# How to precisely understand '願此日繼之，變者，不易者也，吾知一切同要' in this article?

Tags: classical-chinese

I have problem in understanding this Classical Chinese article:

觀地平日入，兩人肩並肩視之，搖曳風前，懷平昔之心，你想甚麽？凝睇俄頃，余但欲捫之須臾耳，潛入爾衷，我欲勾選同秒針，信我明朝微笑，天藍色一點染成，譬如墜愛河時心形圖案。長願一日終。願此日繼之，變者，不易者也，吾知一切同要。輕閉目聽，柔波旋律，無論如何，我今欲聞汝聲。何也？你把我牢包裹。心如廣海，吾敢肯定日易之，使我更堅強，雖相摩肩而過，隨時，以余信之也，良久，無余飾，直，留之，以星反射，水面動，兩人變之。今當保之，永言無窮......我欲勾選同秒針，信我明朝微笑，一點染成天藍色，以其墜愛河時為二人也。

It extracted from a classical Chinese encyclopedia which was created on the Internet and was created after the Internet appeared, so this article might be strange.

Comment: Where did you get this? It's not part of any corpus I have access to. I conjecture it is some novel from 19th to early 20th century, perhaps translated?

Comment: @user2249675 I saw it in an online Classical Chinese Encyclopedia who anyone can edit. The situation of online Classical Chinese Encyclopedia is very rare.

Comment: I searched the words "肩并肩", "爱河" in corpuses I can access. If this is not some made up text, then its date of composition cannot be earlier than 1910, hence not "classical Chinese".

Comment: @user2249675 It works similarly to Baidu Baike, so it is a modern encyclopedia-specific usage of Classical Chinese, after the Internet appeared in 1990, and not extracted from an old pre-ROC encyclopedia. This encyclopedia was also created after the time Internet appeared.

Comment: Then I think it's not something that worths deep investigation. Based on text and context, maybe the author is saying "I know that I want everything after this day that either changes or do not change".

Comment: This is not Classic Chinese though it uses some terms frequently found in Classic Chinese. You don't find 「你想甚麽」, 「使我更堅強」, etc. in Classic Chinese. If the author tried to imitate Classic Chinese at all, then, it's a awkward imitation. This passage is incomprehensible to me. Is "願此日繼之，變者，不易者也，吾知一切同要" your only question about this passage? I'm completely lost at these sentences : "余但欲捫之須臾耳，潛入爾衷，我欲勾選同秒針".

Comment: @Yes, "願此日……吾知一切同要" is my only question.

Comment: User "joehua" has correctly identified this article is out of the hands of a contemporary person who mixed modern words with classical style, but 畫虎不似反成犬, it's not worth digging deeper into.